# C# dictionary Value is changing unintentionally, just when I thought I knew how dictionary worked

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created a dictionary in C# in an attempt to store the latest value from a serial device.  The serial device continuously sends strings of values and each string contains an ID. There are only about 7 IDs and they repeat.  The dictionary is meant to capture the current string of values and store based on the ID so the latest values can be retrieved by ID.  I am only interested in the latest values.  A timer tic (10mS) keeps the serial buffer empty and the data is processed by other methods randomly (once > 1 sec).

The issue I am having is the dictionary value of the key,value pair is a struct:

```
    public struct Frame
    {
        public bool echoMsg;
        public uint pgnID;
        public byte can_dlc;
        public byte[] data;
        public uint timestamp_us;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any helping me understand this issue.

All the values above are being saved with the dictPGN.Add() and if I break during runtime and inspect the dictionary I can see that everything is correct.  However during runtime several more messages come in and processed and when the dictionary is read at a later time the byte[] data valves have been overwritten by strings with different IDs.  I am guessing it is the way I am declaring the byte[] array as the other values in the dictionary remain valid. Ii've tried several things and searched with Google but have not found an answer.

My code looks something like this:

```
 class SerialHardware
{

    public SerialHardware(int hardwareIndexParm) 
    {
        hardwareIndex = hardwareIndexParm;
        mySerialFrame = new SerialFrame();
        mySerialFrame.data = new byte[8];

    }

    private static UsbSerialThing MySerialControl = new UsbSerialThing();
    private static int hardwareIndex;
    private static SerialDeviceThing canID = new SerialDeviceTHing();
    private static UsbSerialThing.frame frameBuffer = new UsbSerialThing.frame();
    private static SerialFrame mySerialFrame = new SerialFrame();



    private static Dictionary <UInt32, SerialFrame> dictPGN = new Dictionary<UInt32, SerialFrame>();  //saves entire frame by PGN
    
    
    public struct Frame
    {
        public bool echoMsg;
        public uint pgnID;
        public byte can_dlc;
        public byte[] data;
        public uint timestamp_us;

    }
    
    public SerialFrame GetPNGFromBuffer( UInt32 pgnIDValue)
    {
        SerialFrame returnFrame;// = new SerialFrame();  <-Just some of the things I've tried
        //returnFrame.data = new byte[8];

        if (dictPGN.ContainsKey(pgnIDValue))
        {
            //returnFrame.data appears to have been updated by other buffer reads**
            returnFrame =  dictPGN[pgnIDValue];
            return returnFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            return new SerialFrame();      //return blank frame 
        }

    }

    private static bool ReadCANDevice()
    {
        bool result = false;
        int bufferSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(frameBuffer);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int readCount = 0;      //return var how many bytes in buffer
        int mSTimeout = 100;   //time in mSec before timeout
        SerialFrame localSerialFrame = new SerialFrame();

        localSerialFrame.data = new byte[8];

        //Read the device
        result = MySerialControl.DeviceBuf(canID, buffer, bufferSize, readCount, mSTimeout);
        if (result)
        {


            mySerialFrame.pgnID = 0x7fffffff & (BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 4)); 
            
            mySerialFrame.can_dlc = buffer[8];

            mySerialFrame.data[0] = buffer[12];
            mySerialFrame.data[1] = buffer[13];
            mySerialFrame.data[2] = buffer[14];
            mySerialFrame.data[3] = buffer[15];
            mySerialFrame.data[4] = buffer[16];
            mySerialFrame.data[5] = buffer[17];
            mySerialFrame.data[6] = buffer[18];
            mySerialFrame.data[7] = buffer[19];
            mySerialFrame.timestamp_us = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 20);      //(uint)buffer[20] | ((uint)buffer[21] << 8) | ((uint)buffer[22] << 16) | ((uint)buffer[23] << 24);


            //save message by PGN_ID
            if (dictPGN.ContainsKey(mySerialFrame.pgnID))
            {
                //dictPGN[mySerialFrame.pgnID] = mySerialFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //byte buffer looks good here! When I break during runtime
                dictPGN.Add(mySerialFrame.pgnID, mySerialFrame);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //nothing to read, buffer empty
            initDevice();
        }

        return result;
    }
    
    //timer event triggers read from serial device
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (ReadCANDevice())
        {
            //empty the buffer
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Dictionary is not thread-safe.  Without any sign of a mutex or lock to protect it, random data corruption is the expected outcome.

Comment: Do you really know what you are doing with all your static members? If I where to make an educated guess I would point to the static members. That said, I would recommend using ConcurrentDictionary as pointed out.

Comment: As Hans Passant points out, you are not protecting the values during read/write.  Each timer tick will instantiate a new thread and you'll start to see the dictionary values updated by one thread while you are in the process of reading it on another thread.

Comment: @Brett I don't think that is true since the values are `struct` and can't be easily updated in the `Dictionary`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `localSerialFrame` versus `mySerialFrame`?

Comment: @Brett I think I see the problem - not the `struct` but the `struct` member `data` which is a reference type.

Comment: Your `if` doesn't seem to implement your desired logic - you are saving the oldest values the way it is written. Remove the `if` and `else` and just uncomment the assignment line so you have `dictPGN[mySerialFrame.pgnID] = mySerialFrame;` to keep the latest value.

Comment: Also, you do have a potential race issue if your processing takes longer than a timer tick and `MySerialControl.DeviceBuf` isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating a `static` variable `mySerialFrame` and setting the reference field `data` to point to an allocated array in the constructor.

In the `ReadCANDevice` method you are re-using that buffer every time you process a message. When you store the `struct` in the `Dictionary`, the fields are copied since a `struct` is a value type, but the value of the `data` field is a pointer to the allocated array from the constructor. So all the entries in the `Dictionary` share the same single array you overwrite each time.

Remove all instances of `mySerialFrame` from the class and only using `localSerialFrame` should fix the issue, since you allocate a new array each time you process a message for the `data` field of `localSerialFrame`.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and NetMage for the insight.  I was not considering the way the value was being handled.  Made bad assumption the data point was being copied by the dictionary but only used the reference.  Using NetMage's guidance things work the way I needed.  Thanks again for all the help.  This question is resolved.